# Show zero-order hold chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library for displaying the graphs, I want to a show [zero-order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) chart. Does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will give you some idea. Through this function finally you will get the LineDataset that you can plot on your graph.

```
private LineData drawLinearGraph(LineData dataGrapSet, ArrayList<Float> yVals, int colorValue, Boolean isFilled) {
        for (int position = 0; position < yVals.size(); position++) {

            int lower = position;
            int upper = position + 1;

            ArrayList<Entry> yValues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
            yValues.add(new Entry(yVals.get(position), lower));
            yValues.add(new Entry(yVals.get(position), upper));

            LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(yValues, "");
            dataset.setLineWidth(2f);
            dataset.setCircleSize(4.5f);
            int color = getResources().getColor(colorValue);
            dataset.setColor(color);
            dataset.setCircleColor(color);
            dataset.setDrawCircles(false);
            dataset.setHighLightColor(color);
            dataset.setValueTextSize(0f);
            dataset.setValueTextColor(color);
            dataset.setDrawCubic(false);
            dataset.setCubicIntensity(0f);
            if (isFilled) {
                dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
            } else {
                dataset.setDrawFilled(false);
            }
            dataset.setFillColor(color);
            dataset.setFillAlpha(255);
            dataset.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);


            if (dataGrapSet != null) {
                dataGrapSet.addDataSet(dataset);
            }
        }
        return dataGrapSet;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for the code snippet, can you explain how it will work?

Comment: Just give this function float values, color of graph and isFilled parameter (isFilled true then graph will be shaded otherwise not) and this function will return you a complete data set to plot on your graph in Zero Order hold.

Comment: You are awesome, worked for me, as it is not efficient because this method is creating complexity, anyhow it is the best solution until zero order hold is implemented by mpChartAndroid Team. Thanks

Comment: Yes that is the problem with this code, not so efficient, just fulfilling the requirement.

Comment: I will add zero hold requirement in mpChartAndroid Github project